# How to set up the processing of empty cells in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with some data.
It looks like i have some required parameters of items on left side of df, and the parameters of items in stock on the right side. So i need to compare a group of "required" parameters with "stock" parameters and choice suitable items on the stock.
If the some "required" cell are empty, this cell should be considered as a value , suitable for **any** "stock" parameters.
How can i do this ?
The data in df may be any type - string, integer, boolean.
[The desired result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ICNp.jpg)

UPD: added code for an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame( {'id' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                    'х_required' : ['metall', 'metall', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                    'y_required' : [10, 10, 7, 7, 7],
                    'х_stock' : ['metall', 'metall', 'wood', 'plastic', 'metall'],
                    'y_stock' : [9, 10, 5, 7, 7] } )
#applying some filters:
df = df[df['х_required'] == df['х_stock']]
df = df[df['y_required'] == df['y_stock']]
print(df)
```

The result is:

```
   id х_required  y_required х_stock  y_stock
1   1     metall          10  metall       10
```

The result i want :

```
   id х_required  y_required х_stock  y_stock
1   1     metall        10.0  metall       10
3   2     NaN           7     plastic      7
4   2     NaN           7     metall       7
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Provide Code and expected Output as text not as image. Thanks

Comment: Your `x_required` contains `U+0445 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER HA` which was confusing.. Just a note. :)

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this with standard Pandas tools. The Pandas documentation states that processing lost data is one of the mandatory steps of working with data. In accordance with this, I wrote the appropriate script that allows me to achieve the desired result. I hope this example will help beginners who are faced with lost data for the first time.